# Debugging Python: Why don't my variables update?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using PyCharm 2019.2 Professional, Win 10 x64, Python 3.7, and IPython 7.11.1.

When running a script in debug mode and hitting a breakpoint, I can execute statements in the IPython prompt. However, I (sometimes?) cannot change the variables values.

For example, I have a dataframe and check on some condition to get a bool-Series, which I then sum up to check the number of thruths in the dataframe, and if there are none, append another dataframe:

(note that this is a simplified example, I'm not looking to improve this specific snipped)

```
a_lim = 0.01
my_mask = df_old['A'] < a_lim
if sum(my_mask) == 0:
    df_new = generate_new_df()
    df_old = df_old.append(df_new, ignore_index=True) \
                   .sort_values(by=['A'], ascending=True) \
                   .reset_index(drop=True)
pass
```

Lets assume df_new contains one row of data that evaluates as True. If I set a breakpoint the if-statement, `sum(my_mask)` would be 0. If I set my breakpoint at `pass`, I can check `df_old` and see the added rows from df_new. At that point, `sum(my_mask)` is still 0. That is fine.

My Problem:

Stopped at `pass`, I evaluate `my_mask = df_old['A'] < a_lim`. Then, I check `sum(my_mask)` and it *still returns 0*. However, if I evaluate `sum(df_old['A'] < a_lim)`, I will get 1 (the expected result).

What is happening behind the scenes, that Python/IPython seems to selectively update variables, and not others?

Thanks!

Comment: Not related but don't use `sum(my_mask)`  use `my_mask.sum()`

Comment: What is `options` and what does `options.append()` return ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Apologies, that was a (potentially critical) mistake by me. I meant `df_old`, which gets then appended the additional data of `df_new`. This might be the worst mistake to make in this question, since my complaint is that `df_old` does not update... Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this bug as well. I have always assumed it is a PyCharm bug not Python. Might be worth raising a bug with JetBrains, think you can do that here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY